# How to use “it” correctly to anticipate an object if it were required?

Tags: sentence-structure

I have read that in English it is used "it" to anticipate the following object if an object is required with verbs such as find or consider.
The common patterns are:
•   [it + adjective + that clause]
•   [it + adjective + to infinitive]

1. I found it hard to accept that my friend had been killed.
2. I find it amazing that they’ve never stopped arguing about football.

But, what is the rule in the following sentences?

3. I’ll leave it to you to decide what to do.
4. She doesn’t like it when you are so quiet.
5. I take it that you agree with me.

I usually say:  I like [going/to go] to the beach.
Is it possible to write sentences 3, 4, and 5 without “it”?

Comment: Have you done any research into *preparatory "it"*? What did you find? Does it apply to any of your example sentences?

Comment: I only found the common patterns • [it + adjective + that clause] • [it + adjective + to infinitive]. They are fine for sentences 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 3 can be written as "I'll leave deciding what to do to you." You can replace "it" with the thing it represents.

Sentence 4 can just have the "it" removed altogether: "She doesn't like when you are so quiet."

Sentence 5 is different, because it uses "it" as part of an idiom. It can't be removed without using a different idiom or phrase altogether.

**take it** ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20it)):

> to assume or suppose